# Simple jQuery accordion toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a simple accordion with toggle states using jQuery. So far so good, but when I click on a different toggle than the initial one that I've clicked on at the start it toggles itself, leaving the previous one with the opened state.

How can one do some kind of a check-up to see if there is another one opened and toggle its state as well?

Here is a [**Fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/cndnnww5/2/) Just mess around with it for a few seconds and you will understand what I mean.

```
// Accordion init
// Hide accordion content on load
$('.accordion-content').hide();
$('.widget-accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

  // State change visuals
  $(this).toggleClass('opened');

  //Expand or collapse this panel
 $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
```

Comment: When opening you have to clear all open classes (from every accordion item which is not clicked actually)and thats it

Comment: Can you provide some code-guidance as well please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment above, here a working fiddle.

The problem is that when you open one accordion item there is no other opened allowed which means that you have to clear every class which stands for the status open...

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cndnnww5/4/)

```
// Accordion init
// Hide accordion content on load
$('.accordion-content').hide();
$('.widget-accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.accordion-toggle').not(this).each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("opened");
  });
  // State change visuals
  $(this).toggleClass('opened');

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
```

Comment: Can I sum up your answer, I will, if you don't want it, just tell me.

Comment: @Spykee - meaning You have a better solution?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind I won't sum it up, just please fix your fiddle.

Comment: @TeaTime , however there is still an issue when You click on the current one to close it. Can we somehow fix this as well?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice you fixed it, my bad =)

Comment: Ofcourse you can. All you have to do is NOT allow the clicked one to get the opened class removed :)

Comment: Fixed it myself I think, just updated your code excerpt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use This instead of `toggleClass`:

```
// State change visuals
 $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('opened');
 $(this).addClass('opened');
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cndnnww5/5/

Comment: Fiddle updated, Check this one. And also there are several more ways.